# Android webview клавиатура

Tags: java, android, webview

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы клавиатура не убиралась при клике на любую область экрана? Если да, то как?

Comment: в манифесте у активити попробуйте добавить атрибут android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"

Comment: Спасибо, это уже пробовал - не работает. Клавиатура показывается при старте приложения

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему установкой фокуса ...

`.focus()` на поле ввода